# Index out of range problem. Would appreciate some feedback

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, syntax-error

I am trying to create a poker game that identifies the best hand out of the two provided hands. Below is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict


values = {"2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "10":10,"J":11, "Q":12, "K":13, "A":14}

valuesOrder = {"2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "10":10,"J":11, "Q":12, "K":13, "A":14}


def straightFlush(hand):
    if flush(hand) and straight(hand):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def fourOfaKind(hand):
    values = [i[0] for i in hand]
    value_counts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
    for v in values:
        value_counts[v]+=1
        if set(value_counts.values()) == set([4,1]):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def fullHouse(hand):
            values = [i[0] for i in hand]
            value_counts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
            for v in values:
                value_counts[v]+=1
            if sorted(value_counts.values()) == [2,3]:
                return True
            return False

def flush(hand):
            suits = [i[2] for i in hand]
            if len(set(suits))==1:
                return True
            else:
                return False

def straight(hand):
            values = [i[0] for i in hand]
            value_counts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
            for v in values:
                value_counts[v] += 1
            rank_values = [valuesOrder[i] for i in values]
            value_range = max(rank_values) - min(rank_values)
            if len(set(value_counts.values())) == 1 and (value_range==4):
                return True
            else:
                #check straight with low Ace
                if set(values) == set(["A", "2", "3", "4", "5"]):
                    return True
                return False

def threeOfaKind(hand):
            values = [i[0] for i in hand]
            value_counts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
            for v in values:
                value_counts[v]+=1
            if set(value_counts.values()) == set([3,1]):
                return True
            else:
                return False

def twoPairs(hand):

            values = [i[0] for i in hand]
            value_counts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
            for v in values:
                value_counts[v]+=1
            if sorted(value_counts.values())==[1,2,2]:
                return True
            else:
                return False

def onePair(hand):
            values = [i[0] for i in hand]
            value_counts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
            for v in values:
                value_counts[v]+=1
            if 2 in value_counts.values():
                return True
            else:
                return False

def checkHand(hand):
            if straightFlush(hand):
                return 9
            elif fourOfaKind(hand):
                return 8
            elif fullHouse(hand):
                return 7
            elif flush(hand):
                return 6
            elif straight(hand):
                return 5
            elif threeOfaKind(hand):
                return 4
            elif twoPairs(hand):
                return 3
            elif onePair(hand):
                return 2
            else: 
                return 1

def compare_hands(x,y):
    x = checkHand(hand1)
    y = checkHand(hand2)
    print(x)
    print(y)
    if (x > y):
        print("hand1")
    elif (y > x):
        print("hand2")
    else:
        print("tie")


hand1 = ('J C, 7 S, 9 D, 6 H, 5 C')
hand2 = ('9 C, J S, 6 D, 5 H, 7 C')

compare_hands(hand1, hand2)
```

The code only works when I set hand1 and hand 2 as below. Basically each card in a string item.

```
hand1 = ("2 C","3 D","4 S","A D","6 H")
hand2 = ("2 C","5 C","4 C","9 C","7 C")
```

But I want it to accept the hands as below. All the cards in one string

```
hand1 = ('J C, 7 S, 9 D, 6 H, 5 C')
hand2 = ('9 C, J S, 6 D, 5 H, 7 C')
```

How can I get this to work? I am new to python so if this may be an easy fix or if I have overcomplicated the code, I apologize in advance. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `hand = ("2 C","3 D","4 S","A D","6 H")` --> 5 values in this tuple ||||| `hand = ('J C, 7 S, 9 D, 6 H, 5 C')` --> Only 1 value: I think the error comes from that

Comment: Is there any way I can convert that one value tuple into a 5 value tuple so it works properly?

Comment: `"J C, 7 S, 9 D, 6 H, 5 C".split(",")` --> `["J C","7 S","9 D","6 H","5 C"]` - You can use [`split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp).

Comment: the `('example string)` without a comma is taken as a function, to get a list just add a comma like this `('example string', )`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function:

```py
hand1=tuple('J C, 7 S, 9 D, 6 H, 5 C'.split(","))
hand2=tuple('9 C, J S, 6 D, 5 H, 7 C'.split(","))
```